# Using mini-images to make up an image (processing)

Tags: processing

In my sketch you have a bunch of mini-images that will make up an input picture.
Currently my input is a picture of a hand and my small images are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSN09.jpg
(the 3 test mini images are transparent, so drag them from imgur, they are currently black)
and my current output looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWfhX.jpg

I'm not sure why they are overlapping like this, I've made the background of each mini-image transparent so that they can overlap, so I need a way to scale them out.

My main problem that I'd like to resolve is I need to make sure that my mini-images make up just the hand, and not the white background around the hand. I figured that if the mini-images were only assigned to the shades of the hand, then the white background wouldn't even count.

I'm not sure how to do that. Help?

CODE:

```java
final int len=25;
final float thresh=170;

boolean newDesign=false;
PImage pic;

ArrayList<PImage> imgContainer;
int n=3;

void setup() {  
  size(800, 800, P2D);
  colorMode(RGB, 255);
  background(250, 250, 250);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  //imageMode(CENTER);

  pic=loadImage("hand.jpg");
  pic.resize(width, height);

  color c1 = color(200,25,25);
  color c2 = color(25, 255, 200);  

  imgContainer=new ArrayList<PImage>();
PImage pimg1=loadImage("test0.png");
pimg1.resize(50, 50);
imgContainer.add(pimg1);
PImage pimg2=loadImage("test1.png");
pimg2.resize(50, 50);
imgContainer.add(pimg2);
PImage pimg3=loadImage("test2.png");
pimg1.resize(50, 50);
imgContainer.add(pimg3);
  noLoop();
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  if (newDesign==false) {
    return;
  }

  pic.loadPixels();

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y+=18) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x+=18) {
      // Get the color stored in the pixel
      int index=y*width+x;
      color pixelValue = pic.pixels[index];
      // Determine the brightness of the pixel
      float pixelBrightness = brightness(pixelValue);

      float imgPicked=constrain(pixelBrightness/thresh, 0, n-1);
      image(imgContainer.get((int)imgPicked),x,y);

    }
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  newDesign=!newDesign;
  redraw();

    }
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code by pasting your code into the editor, highlighting it, and then pressing the code button to format it all as a single block instead of formatting each line as a separate block. Please also provide a link to all of the image files that we need. Better yet, post a link to a CodePen that shows your program running.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that. You can drag all the images from imgur and itll work.

Comment: I'm still not totally sure what effect you're going for. Do you have a mock of what you expect this code to do? What exactly do you mean when you say *"I figured that if the mini-images were only assigned to the shades of the hand, then the white background wouldn't even count"*? Where are you only assigning anything to the shades in the hand?

Comment: Hey. So im pretty much trying to do this exactly: http://www.generative-gestaltung.de/P_4_3_2_01 But instead of text characters, I would like to use my own mini-images. Right now the mini-images are being assigned to the background of my hand image when I dont need them to be. Right now im not assigning anything to shades.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. Where in your code are you preventing the images from displaying over the background, or causing the images to display only on top of the hand?

Comment: That I am not sure, thats what im trying to figure out. I think the pixel value and the rest is what causes the images to display on top of the hand. I think if there were a way of making it not apply to anything white but only the shaded areas, it would work out. Not sure how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

You're asking how to only show your small images on a particular part of your larger image.

At a high level, what you want to do is loop over the coordinates in the large image where you want to draw your small images, then get the pixel at each coordinate, check it, and only draw a small image if the pixel matches some critera.

You can loop over the coordinates with a nested `for` loop (you already do this part), and you can get the pixel color of that coordinate using the `get()` function (you sort-of do this). Then you can use an `if` statement to check that color and only draw the small image if it matches some criteria.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_get_.html), but there's a very basic example:

```java
for (int y = 0; y < height; y+= 100) {
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x+= 100) {

    color pixelValue = largeImage.get(x, y);

    if(red(pixelValue) > 128){
      image(smallImage, x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

This code assumes that the window is the same size as the large image. It then loops over the coordinates in the large image (only looking at every 100th pixel), and gets the color at that pixel. It then checks whether that pixel has a red value greater than `128`, and if so it draws the small image at that coordinate.

This is just an example, so you're going to have to modify the approach to fit your needs. But the basic idea remains: iterate over the pixels, get the color, check that color, and only draw the smaller image if the color matches some criteria.

This is also how the image you posted with the colored letters works, only instead of drawing a smaller image, they draw a character using the color of the underlying pixel.

Comment: Great!! I dont quite understand the largeImage and smallImage part though, are these functions or am I to change them to put in hand.jpg and the small images from PImage?

Comment: This is just example code, but yes, `largeImage` would be your hand image, and `smallImage` would by your smaller "black" images. You'd probably want to expand this code to draw three small images instead of just one, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: Gotcha. Im just confused how I would format it. Right now I have:                                  `color pixelValue = loadImage("hand.jpg").get(x, y);`    is that correct?

Comment: What happened when you tried that? It might work, but you'd probably want to split it up into two steps. Load your image once at the beginning, in the `setup()` function. You're already doing most of what I'm suggesting. You can probably pretty much just use the `pic` variable instead of my `largeImage` variable. Again, my code was just an example. I only used `largeImage` because I wanted to make it clear exactly which image the code would use.

Comment: I think it works- im not getting an error, but im still confused about how I would get the small images in, being that they are in their own Pimage container. Sorry, im a bit of a newbie.

Comment: @guyintightpants I'm not totally sure what you mean. You can just draw the smaller images using the `image()` function, like I've done in the example code. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes...so same thing? `image(loadImage("test1.png"), x, y);` ? Or do I need to put in Pimage? >.<

Comment: @guyintightpants You should just try things out and see if they do what you expect. But keep in mind that `loadImage()` does return a `PImage`, and you probably only want to load each image once, in the `setup()` function. You're already doing all of this in your current code.

Comment: Ah im not getting it :|  The background still remains the same. Probably not doing it right. Thanks for the help though

Comment: I changed it to `pic.get (x , y);`, im assuming thats what you meant.

Comment: Yes (afaik) but im still stuck on how to load the mini-images in. I also tried taking some of the code that Thomas linked below and I changed img to pic https://pastebin.com/QvTxjPuG  But this doesnt quite work either

Comment: @guyintightpants You're already loading the small images in your original code. My example code doesn't change any of that.

Comment: Right...so what do I put in for image(smallImage) then? I tried Pimage but that didnt work out.

Comment: @guyintightpants It depends entirely on exactly what you're trying to do. Maybe try just starting with a single small image? Work your way up from there, and post an updated [mcve] in a new question post if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Load all the mini-images to be the hand.

Answer (score -1):

I think the code on this website provides a solution for your problem.

https://lernprocessing.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/projekt-bild-aus-text/

It is a German website (some of the code comments are in German as well), so feel free to ask if you have any problems.

Comment: This should work! I hadnt seen this version, the code im using above is a modified version of a different Generative Gestaltung piece. Checking out and will get back to you. This is a text version or does it work with images too? I see that the white background is fixed in yours.

Comment: Which part of your modified code would I use being that I think this is for text and not images? I see the greyscale line, but im not sure how I'd incorperate it?

Comment: Please don't post link-only questions.

Comment: @Thomas Sallaberger I tried putting in https://pastebin.com/QvTxjPuG  from your modified version but it doesnt seem to be working. any ideas?